# Using ArcPy to populate field in new feature layer

Tags: arcpy

I have a function that makes a new feature layer and it is being created. But how would I use arcpy to update and populate a field in that new feature layer? I've been trying to use an UpdateCursor to the specific field and loop through but it's not working and the values remain null. Basically it looks like this:

```
new_drop = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(drop_features, parameter_out)



with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(new_drop, ['WORK_REQUIRED']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = "YES"
        cursor.updateRow(row)
del row, cursor
```

what am I missing here? I've seen the post here does this exact same thing, its just that there is no makefeaturelayer call in that code. I've even tried to specify the path where the new layer is being made and use that as a parameter(where it says new_drop in updateCursor)

Comment: The feature layer generated by MakeFeatureLayer in your case would be whatever you made "parameter_out".  You should be using that in your UpdateCursor.  The "new_drop" is a result object and not a layer.

Comment: CalculateField_management is a better resource for this than UpdateCursor

Comment: From a syntax perspective, what you have written should work.  Are you using ArcGIS Desktop/ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro?  What version of software?  What is the data source behind `drop_features`, file geodatabase, enterprise geodatabase, hosted feature layer, etc...?  Where are you running this code, Jupyter Notebook, interactive Python window, etc...?